# unable to edit tinyproxy.conf file on Raspberry Pi B+

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I added tinyproxy following this link: (http://www.the-hawkes.de/a-web-proxy-with-tinyproxy-and-ssh-tunnel.html). After installing I tried to edit tinyproxy.conf and got this error:

```
pi@raspberrypib /etc $ sudo edit tinyproxy.conf
Warning: unknown mime-type for "tinyproxy.conf" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no "edit" mailcap rules found for type "application/octet-stream"
```

pi@raspberrypib /etc $

I double checked and the file does indeed exist:

```
pi@raspberrypib /etc $ ls tiny*
tinyproxy.conf

pi@raspberrypib /etc $
```

I also tried to look at the mailcap.order file and also got an error:

```
pi@raspberrypib /etc $ dir mail*
mailcap  mailcap.order

pi@raspberrypib /etc $ edit mailcap.order
Warning: unknown mime-type for "mailcap.order" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no write permission for file "mailcap.order"

pi@raspberrypib /etc $ sudo edit mailcap.order
Warning: unknown mime-type for "mailcap.order" -- using "application/octet-stream"
Error: no "edit" mailcap rules found for type "application/octet-stream"

pi@raspberrypib /etc $
```

Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `sudo nano tinyproxy.conf`

Comment: Thanks, that worked. It's been two months and I forgot that minor detail.  OK to close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, thanks Colonel Thirty Two, I was using edit instead of nano

```
sudo nano tinyproxy.conf
```